# A basic question on Calculus.

Tags: calculus

I was studying basics of calculus and came up with a question.
The question is as follows:

Let us consider three functions $f(x)$, $g(x)$ and $h(x)$.

The domain of all the three functions is $(0,\infty)$.

The co-domain is the set of all real numbers.

All the three functions are continuous for all the real numbers in its domain.
And they follow the specific relation:
$(f(x))^2 = (g(x))^2+(h(x))^2$

And lastly limit of the functions $f,g,h$ as $x$ approaches $0$ are $a,b,c$ respectively.

Then, will $a^2 = b^2 + c^2$?

It seems to me that it should be true but  I am unable to prove it.
If yes then please provide me a proof for this.
It may be a trivial question but I am unable to solve it.
Thanks.

Comment: Consider the limit rules as they pertain to sums and products.

Comment: @JohnDouma by the help of the limit rules the right hand of the equality will approach the value b×b+c×c and the corresponding left side will approach the value of a×a when x approaches 0. But I am unable to show that the the equality will pertain when I will insert those values in the corresponding right and left hand side. As the equality only holds for those x which belongs to the domain of the function.

Comment: $$a^2=(lim f)^2=lim f^2=lim(g^2 + h^2)= (lim g)^2 + (lim h)^2 = b^2 + c^2$$

Comment: There is no left hand limit. Consider the domain.

Comment: @John Douma by left and right I meant left and right side of the equality.

Comment: Continuity is not required.